# C++ Constructor Overloading - Why does it say I need parenthesis?

Tags: c++, debugging, constructor

Here is the code for my header file:

```
#ifndef NEURAL_NETWORK_H
#define NEURAL_NETWORK_H

#include <vector>

#include "genome.h"
#include "node.h"

class NeuralNetwork {
protected:
    std::vector<Node> m_nodes;

public:
    NeuralNetwork(std::vector<Node> nodes);
    NeuralNetwork(Genome genome);

    void update();
};

#endif
```

However when I try and compile it, it says:

```
neuralNetwork.h:15:23: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘genome’
  NeuralNetwork(Genome genome);
```

However there are no unbalanced brackets, and I see nothing wrong with the code, I am assuming that this is something to do with constructor overloading, but after researching online, there doesn't seem to be any special rules.
Also, when I replace Genome with int

I am using C++ 11.

Comment: Can you please try to create a [Minimal, ***Complete***, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us?

Comment: Possibly `Genome` is in a different namespace?

Comment: You don't provide enough information. There is nothing obviously wrong with the code you show here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a circular dependency which you need to break. One usually does that by using *forward declarations*.

In fact, there's nothing in your `neuralNetwork.h` header file (as shown) that actually *needs* the full definition of `Genome` which means you can replace

```
#include "genome.h"
```

with

```
class Genome;
```

You still need `#include "genome.h"` in the *source file* though, where you define (implement) the constructor.